# Count unique categories for each sample in a dataframe and display unique categories

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a data frame example

```
       Sample1    Sample2      Sample3      Sample4        
Cat     0           0            0           1
Dog     0           0            1           0
Rabbit  0           0            0           1
Mouse   1           1            1           1 
Snake   1           1            0           1
....
```

I would like to count the number of Unique animals for each sample. And ideally generate a list of some sort for each sample that shows what the unique animals are. 
So you can see that cats are unique to sample 4,dogs are unique to sample 3, and Rabbits are unique to sample 3.
However sample 1 and sample 2 do not have any unique animals because other samples contain these animals.
I have used this to count `sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x)))` but the data set is so large, I cannot tell if this is accurate.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Welcome on our site! Not the best reproducible example and a quick internet search should give you an answer. What I would do it to give everything that is above zero a 1 and then sum the columns, that will give you the number of unique otus for each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `lapply` like this:

```
uniqueList = lapply(df, unique)
numberOfUniques = lapply(uniqueList, length)
```

**Example:**

Using `mtcars` for `df`

```
> uniqueList

$mpg
 [1] 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5
[20] 13.3 27.3 26.0 15.8 19.7 15.0

$cyl
[1] 6 4 8

$disp
 [1] 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0  78.7  75.7  71.1 120.1
[17] 318.0 304.0 350.0 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0

$hp
 [1] 110  93 175 105 245  62  95 123 180 205 215 230  66  52  65  97 150  91 113 264 335 109

$drat
 [1] 3.90 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.07 2.93 3.00 3.23 4.08 4.93 4.22 3.70 3.73 4.43 3.77
[20] 3.62 3.54 4.11

$wt
 [1] 2.620 2.875 2.320 3.215 3.440 3.460 3.570 3.190 3.150 4.070 3.730 3.780 5.250 5.424 5.345 2.200
[17] 1.615 1.835 2.465 3.520 3.435 3.840 3.845 1.935 2.140 1.513 3.170 2.770 2.780

$qsec
 [1] 16.46 17.02 18.61 19.44 20.22 15.84 20.00 22.90 18.30 18.90 17.40 17.60 18.00 17.98 17.82 17.42
[17] 19.47 18.52 19.90 20.01 16.87 17.30 15.41 17.05 16.70 16.90 14.50 15.50 14.60 18.60

$vs
[1] 0 1

$am
[1] 1 0

$gear
[1] 4 3 5

$carb
[1] 4 1 2 3 6 8
```

Comment: Thanks! However I think this is calculating the number of unique values, however I want the number of unique categories (as row names in my data set). For example if Otu4 has a zero in all columns but column FS_45 then Otu4 is unique to that column. I would like  list of all Otus unique to each column.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get if you wanted number of unique values by row or column. I propose both

If you have voluminous data, you should have a look at `data.table`.

Let's take a silly example

```r
library(data.table)
df = data.table(
  x = c(1,2),
  y = c(1,1),
  z = c(2,3)
)
```

## unique by column

Simplest answer:

```r
df[,lapply(.SD,uniqueN)]
```

## unique by row

A solution could be to tranform your data into long format and make a count by group

Then, you generate a row identifier (`seq_len(.N)` means 1 to *n* in `data.table` verbs). You use that column to pivot your data (`melt` is a built-in function in `data.table`, equivalent to `pivot_long` in tidyr) and then use `uniqueN` built-in function from `data.table`.

```r
df[,'id' := seq_len(.N)]
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = "id")
df2[, (count_unique = uniqueN(value)), by = "id"]

df2[, (count_unique = uniqueN(value)), by = "id"]
   id V1
1:  1  2
2:  2  3
```

Comment: Hi sorry maybe I wasn't clear. I want the number of unique categories (as row names in my data set). For example, if Otu4 has a zero in all columns but column FS_45 then Otu4 is unique to that column. I would like list of all Otus unique to each column.

Comment: So it's the number of unique values by row, right ? e.g. in your example, otu1 has 4 unique values (or 3 if you exclude zeros) while otu2 has 1 unique value (or zero if you exclude zeros). Otherwise, we will need a reproducible example  to be able to answer to you

Comment: I am not worried about the values, I just want to know how to find out if Otu1 or Otu2 or Otu3 ...etc is unique to each column, so that all the other columns contain a zeros for that specific Otu. I will edit the question a little.

Comment: I have made the question easier to understand, thanks for your help so far!